# Resolving circular dependency between ExtUtils::MakeMaker and Test::Harness

Tags: git, perl, rhel6, makemaker

I'm trying to compile git 2.5.2 on RHEL6 into my home directory and it requires a perl module ExtUtils::MakeMaker. ExtUtils::MakeMaker isn't installed in the standard locations and installing packages (via yum) is impossible due to organizational limitations.

ExtUtils::MakeMaker requires Test::Harness, which also isn't installed. Test::Harness depends on ExtUtils::MakeMaker, is there a way to break this dependency or a way to compile git without depending on ExtUtils::MakeMaker?

Output when trying to install ExtUtils::MakeMaker:

```
Using included version of CPAN::Meta (2.120351) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of Parse::CPAN::Meta (1.4405) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of CPAN::Meta::YAML (0.008) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of ExtUtils::Manifest (1.65) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of JSON::PP (2.27203) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of ExtUtils::Install (1.54) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of CPAN::Meta::Requirements (2.127) because it is not already installed.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for ExtUtils::MakeMaker
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Can't locate Test/Harness.pm in @INC (@INC contains: bundled/CPAN-Meta bundled/JSON-PP-Compat5006 bundled/Parse-CPAN-Meta bundled/CPAN-Meta-YAML bundled/File-
Temp bundled/ExtUtils-Manifest bundled/JSON-PP bundled/ExtUtils-Install bundled/Scalar-List-Utils bundled/CPAN-Meta-Requirements lib . /usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at Makefile.PL line 143.
```

Output from git make:

```
    SUBDIR perl
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL PREFIX='/home/svc_rrtd/local' INSTALL_BASE='' --localedir='/home/svc_rrtd/local/share/locale'
Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Makefile.PL line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 3.
make[1]: *** [perl.mak] Error 2
make: *** [perl/perl.mak] Error 2
```

Comment: how are you trying to install stuff?  what error actually happens when you try installing EU::MM?  Test::Harness should not be a dependency.

Comment: ExtUtils::MakeMaker is a core module; if you have Perl 5, you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker. Please show the commands you're running and show the exact message that says EU::MM can't be found.

Comment: use yum to install the missing perl dev tools like perl-CPAN etc ...

Comment: Added output of commands.  We don't have root and our support vendor is grossly incompetent, yum isn't an option.

Comment: Have you added to PERL5LIB ? If your vendor perl installation is crippled, and vendor isn't helping, install your own perl

Comment: I've encountered broken system perls before, which might be part of the problem. Personally I'd try to use perlbrew or plenv to install a local version of perl (you don't have root - right?), then *hopefully* you have a stable base. That said, I'd check for the prerequisites first (expect, openssl etc) seeing as you don't have sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling a more recent (2.17 Q2 2018, almost 3 years later) version of Git might prove easier, since the build procedure for `perl`/ part has been greatly simplified by weaning Git off of `MakeMaker`.

See [commit 7a7bfc7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a7bfc7adceec0be66aec3a4999be2f9b33ccc24) (02 Jan 2018) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
See [commit 805a378](https://github.com/git/git/commit/805a378649d69aa1503fd2a22afc5490c6e9c2d3) (22 Dec 2017), and [commit 20d2a30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20d2a30f8ffe14deb09b4e6fc7b70ead53b315f0) (10 Dec 2017) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ed1b87e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed1b87ef910fe38dfb9cf044f5c946adfab0c5e3), 13 Feb 2018)</sup>

Ævar explains:

> Replace the `perl/Makefile.PL` and the fallback `perl/Makefile` used under
> `NO_PERL_MAKEMAKER=NoThanks` with a much simpler implementation heavily
> inspired by how the i18n infrastructure's build process works.
> See [commit 5e9637c from Git v1.7.9-rc0, Nov. 2011](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e9637c629702e3d41ad01d95956d1835d7338e0).
>
> The reason for having the `Makefile.PL` in the first place is that it
> was initially building a Perl C binding to interface with `libgit` ([commit b1edc53d0, Git  v1.4.3-rc1, June 2006](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b1edc53d062c4f6adae08a15be08d6e7bccd242e)), this functionality, that was removed ([commit 18b0fc1, Git v1.4.3-rc1, Sept. 2006](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18b0fc1ce1ef92716d4c5d5c7acd5d5a61a0a556)) before `Git.pm` ever made it to the `master` branch.
>
> We've since since started maintaining a fallback `perl/Makefile`, as
> `MakeMaker` wouldn't work on some platforms ([commit f848718, Git v1.5.0-rc0, Dec. 2006](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f848718a6980ebda0eb5afb2ca49c3bc1e7b2b1d)).
> That's just the tip of the iceberg. We have the `PM.stamp` hack in the top-level `Makefile` ([commit ee9be06, Git v1.7.12-rc1, Jul. 2012](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee9be06770223238c6a22430eb874754dd22dfb0)) to detect whether we need to regenerate the `perl/perl.mak`, which I fixed just recently to deal with issues like the `perl` version changing from under us ([commit c59c4939, Git v2.13.0-rc0, March 2017](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c59c4939c2ecef21f5dd913698552bd0fffe5ebb)).
>
> There is absolutely no reason for why this needs to be so complex anymore.
> All we're getting out of this elaborate Rube Goldberg machine was copying `perl/*` to `perl/blib/*` as we do a string-replacement on
> the `*.pm` files to hard-code `@@LOCALEDIR@@` in the source, as well as
> pod2man-ing `Git.pm` & friends.
>
> So replace the whole thing with something that's pretty much a copy of how we generate `po/build/**.mo` from `po/*.po`, just with a small [`sed(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) command instead of `msgfmt`.
> As that's being done, rename the files from `*.pm` to `*.pmc` just to indicate that they're generated (see ["`perldoc -f require`"](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eneilb/UNIVERSAL-require-0.18/lib/UNIVERSAL/require.pm)).

---

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), build procedure gets cleaned-up.

See [commit 8c55753](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c55753c68e9c3e56f7a0d96301d2211d9e4ae35) (12 May 2021), and [commit 256c2dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/256c2dc42c812e4868532b88155f60f0a269c821), [commit 368a50d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/368a50d9eea16e8e1181ce12d5c3c1d50216b688), [commit 3d49f72](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d49f7220a41147b17c1d826b9c87452b5f68c2c), [commit 4070c9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4070c9e09fc4295e5b2f8a7cbb5bae1936fdeef8) (05 May 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2e2ed74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e2ed74be03993706d467e4b8e785afeb5f173d9), 20 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`perl`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/256c2dc42c812e4868532b88155f60f0a269c821): use mock i18n functions under `NO_GETTEXT=Y`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change the logic of the i18n functions I added in [5e9637c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e9637c629702e3d41ad01d95956d1835d7338e0) ("`i18n`: add infrastructure for translating Git with gettext", 2011-11-18, Git v1.7.9-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2dccad3c6f9df2b1eea7eb5617e2748a7f2daa40)) to use pass-through functions when `NO_GETTEXT` is defined.
>
> This speeds up the compilation time of commands that use this library when `NO_GETTEXT=Y` is in effect.
> Loading it and `POSIX.pm` is around 20ms on my machine, whereas it takes 2ms to just instantiate Perl itself.

Answer (score 0):

Where is it installed?
Simply add that directory to [PERL5LIB](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlrun#PERL5LIB)

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/user/stuff/lib/perl5:$PERL5LIB
```

**update:** try installing the prerequisites for git, something like

```
$ sudo yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel \
  openssl-devel perl-devel zlib-devel
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext \
  libz-dev libssl-dev
```

Thats a quote from http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git